# Sent comments notifications to multiple users

Tags: comments, email

I am new to wordpress 
I want to send email notifications for commenting in blogs. Currently it is going to only one user.
I tried 'comment notifier' plugin but got negative result.
I tried the below code

```
add_filter('comment_notification_recipients', 'override_comment_notice_repicient', 10, 2);
function override_comment_notice_repicient($emails, $comment_id) {
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
    if ( empty( $comment ) )
        return $emails;
    $post = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );

    return array('mymail@gmail.com');
}
```

but it isn't working. I googled it but couldn't get anything. Please help me solve it.

Comment: HI Rishi, Welcome.  The code should return the array of emails to which you wish notifocations to go. Currently you appear to be returning one email address?   Note also that the code does not need to check empty comment etc.  That is done in wp. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_notify_postauthor/ where the filter is applied.

Comment: @anmari Thanks for the reply. But the reference you gave is for sending notifications to the post author. I need to send it to other admins.

Comment: Wordpress sends to the author by default, but gives the filter you mentioned above so you can add to the list of email addresses.  Look at the link, scroll down, open the source code and find the where it says "Filters the list of email addresses to receive a comment notification.
     *
     * By default, only post authors are notified of comments. This filter allows
     * others to be added."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
 add_filter('comment_notification_recipients', 'override_comment_notice_repicient', 10, 2);
    function override_comment_notice_repicient($emails, $comment_id) {  
        $admins = get_users( array(
            'role__in'     => array('administrator'),
        ) );
        foreach ( $admins as $user ) {
            $emails[] =  $user->user_email;
        }
        return ($emails);
    }
```

Comment: it is not working. I used die('testing') inside the function. it is not even entering the function. Are there some other issues which I need to solve?

Comment: It's working for me.  I added error_log calls as per below.  The function is entered & array of emails returned.     Check your error_log location to see the output (better than die, with die, the output may be trapped not seen, and of course, the result is not passed through and action not taken.
'..
   error_log("in Function");
 $admins = get_users( array(
        'role__in'     => array('administrator'),
    ) );
 foreach ( $admins as $user ) {
  $emails[] =  $user->user_email;
 }
 error_log(print_r($emails,true));
    return ($emails);
..'

Comment: I even added an error_log in the wp function where it sends to each email.  Line 1563 in the code of https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_notify_postauthor/   and it's definitely getting there ;)   Had all my  admin users listed there.

Comment: A good way to test with emails on your localhost is using the tool referred to here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773288/configure-wamp-server-to-send-email?noredirect=1&lq=1